# How can I assign a return value to a variable in python not the memory address?

Tags: python, pyserial

I have two serial ports connected to the same computer. The below code will print the ports are connected to my machine. I want to assign the port values only to a variable so I can use down in the code.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print p
```

the output is

```
>>> /dev/ttyS0 - ttyS0
/dev/ttyUSB1 - FT232R USB UART
/dev/ttyUSB0 - USB-Serial Controller D
```

I want to parse those info and assign the following:

```
var1 = ttyS0
var2 = ttyUSB1
var3 = ttyUSB0
```

How can I do that in python3?

Comment: You **never** assign to a memory address in Python, you are fundamentally confused about the semantics of assignments

Comment: What type of thing is `p` - if you `print type(p)` what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#module-serial.tools.list_ports) list_port return a list of ListPortInfo object. This object has some properties (device, name...)

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print (p.name)
```